# Date record problem

Tags: jquery, sql-server-2008

I'm using properly JQuery Datepicker script for date entry in the form.When I record within database(SQL Server 2008) the values which are entered,I got the following error.

```
DateTime adate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtaddeddate.Text);
```

Error:

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

Comment: Ok, give us some hints here. What is the value of txtaddeddate.Text? Are you outputting a string literal as mm/dd/yyyy, d/m/y, yyyymmdd, something else?

Comment: This isn't a SQL error. And what code/language sits between jQuery in the browser and the database call on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ParseExact`,

From MSDN:

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent. The format of the string representation must
>   match a specified format exactly or an exception is thrown.
>
> This member is overloaded. For complete information about this member,
>   including syntax, usage, and examples, click a name in the overload
>   list.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx

You didn't state what programming language you were using, I am assuming C#.  And this is definately not a SQL Server issue.

What format are you giving the string? (dd/MM/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy or ...)

Try this:

```
string myDate = "12/12/2011";
string f = "dd/MM/yyyy";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(myDate, f, null);
```

Change `f` to fit your format.  It also appears you are getting the date from a user so I passed `null` for the format provider interface, that makes it use the current culture.